# Wall not moving when doing setPosition cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm converting my android game, previously written in Java to cocos2d-x. In this game I need to spawn walls at a few random positions, so I call setPosition on my sprite in my init method but the position on the x-axis isn't changed (they are changed on the y-axis though Oo).
 The position does change when I call it on onTouchBegun() and change it there, it just doesn't work on that initial call. I can't find any related problem on google and I'm all out of ideas.
I'll add the code I use to spawn the walls down below:

```
void WallPair::init(cocos2d::Layer *scene, float height, float width, float gapWidth, Vec2 position){
this->position = position;
this->height = height;
this->scene = scene;
this->gapWidth = gapWidth;
//Pointtrigger (obv)
pointWall = Sprite::create();
pointWall->setScale(gapWidth, height);
pointWall->setPosition(position.x, position.y);
auto pointTrigger = PhysicsBody::createBox(Size(gapWidth, height));
pointTrigger->setDynamic(false);
pointTrigger->setGravityEnable(false);
pointTrigger->setCategoryBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::POINT);
pointTrigger->setCollisionBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::NONE);
pointTrigger->setContactTestBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::PLAYER);
pointWall->setPhysicsBody(pointTrigger);
scene->addChild(pointWall, 2);

leftWall = Sprite::create(texture);
leftWall->setScale(width/leftWall->getContentSize().width, height/leftWall->getContentSize().height);
Size wallSize = Size(leftWall->getContentSize().width * leftWall->getScaleX(), leftWall->getContentSize().height * leftWall->getScaleY());
std::cout << "POSRES: " << (position.x - gapWidth - wallSize.width) << " ::: LEFT;" << std::endl;

std::cout << "LPOS: " << leftWall->getPosition().x << ", LSIZE: " << wallSize.width << std::endl;
std::cout << "SCALE: " << leftWall->getScaleX() << ", " << leftWall->getScaleY() << std::endl;
  // std::cout << "contentSizeLW: " << leftWall->getContentSize().width << " pos: " << (position.x - gapWidth - leftWall->getContentSize().width/2) <<", SCALE: " << leftWall->getScaleY()<<std::endl;
//leftWall->setContentSize(Size(leftWall->getContentSize().width, height));
scene->addChild(leftWall, 2);
auto pbl = PhysicsBody::createBox(wallSize, PhysicsMaterial(0.1f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
pbl->setDynamic(false);
pbl->setGravityEnable(false);
pbl->setCategoryBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::WALL);
pbl->setCollisionBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::PLAYER);
pbl->setContactTestBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::PLAYER);
leftWall->setPhysicsBody(pbl);
leftWall->setPosition(position.x - gapWidth - wallSize.width, position.y);


rightWall = Sprite::create(texture);
rightWall->setScale(width/rightWall->getContentSize().width, height/rightWall->getContentSize().height);
wallSize = Size(rightWall->getContentSize().width * rightWall->getScaleX(), rightWall->getContentSize().height * rightWall->getScaleY());
std::cout << "POSRES: " << (position.x + gapWidth + wallSize.width) << ":::RIGHT;" << std::endl;
//rightWall->setContentSize(Size(rightWall->getContentSize().width * rightWall->getScaleX(), height));


std::cout << "RPOS: " << rightWall->getPosition().x << std::endl;
//rightWall->setContentSize(Size(rightWall->getContentSize().width, height));
 //  std::cout << "contentSizeRW: " << rightWall->getContentSize().width << " pos: " << (position.x + gapWidth + rightWall->getContentSize().width/2) << ", SCALE: " << rightWall->getScaleY() <<std::endl;
scene->addChild(rightWall, 2);
pbl = PhysicsBody::createBox(wallSize, PhysicsMaterial(0.1f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
pbl->setDynamic(false);
pbl->setGravityEnable(false);
pbl->setCategoryBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::WALL);
pbl->setCollisionBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::PLAYER);
pbl->setContactTestBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::PLAYER);

rightWall->setPhysicsBody(pbl);
rightWall->setPosition(position.x + gapWidth + wallSize.width, position.y);


}
```

The WallPair's onTouch method:

```
    void touch(){
    leftWall->setPosition(leftWall->getPositionX() - 50.0f, leftWall->getPositionY());
    rightWall->setPosition(rightWall->getPositionX() + 50.0f, rightWall->getPositionY());
}
```

EDIT: 
Just to clarify: 
The problem is not the touch method. That works correctly. The problem is  WallPair::init(). It puts the sprites at an xpos of 0 even though getPosition tells me they should be all over the place (ranging from -500 to +1500). But they still are on 0.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add your onTouchBegun method

Comment: What class WallPair is extending? And can you disable physics stuff for a movement? I think it's related to that.

Comment: @Makalele WallPair is not extending any class, it's basically three Sprite pointers a few floats and a couple of methods to make managing walls more convenient.

Comment: @musikov Just added it !

Comment: Is your `touch` method called? Where do you register touch handling?

Comment: @musikov My touch method is working correctly, the problem is the initialization code. The walls seem to get placed in xpos of 0. Even though getPosition tells me they are at like -250 and 1000.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after a lot of time Googling, debuging, testing and coding I found the problem.
If I use a Transition when I do replaceScene I am not able to manually set the position of sprites with physicsbodies, but I'm able to do so without transition.

All I did was change the replaceScene code:

```
from:
    director->replaceScene(TransitionFlipX::create(2, scene));
to:
    director->replaceScene(scene);
```

And it now works!